# IBM Watson Conversation API: “Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response”

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors, fetch-api, watson-conversation

I created a React-Native app that connected to the Watson REST APIs. Using the fetch library that is part of the ReactNative, everything was working well for getting the Workspaces list, like this:

```
    const myAuth = new Buffer(USR+':'+PWD).toString('base64');
    const myInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Origin': '',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + myAuth,
        }
    };

    return fetch(URL, myInit)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => { ... }
```

I am now moving to React (rather than ReactNative) and the [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) library. The same code does not work. First I got the error that:

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Then reading the tens of threads about these type of issues it just became black magic. Adding headers for Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and the such. Nothing really worked so far. Eventually the problem became:

> Request header field access-control-allow-headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Can someone point me please to an example or code that works please?

==============

UPDATES ...

Thank you @sideshowbarker and @FakeRainBrigand. I guess then a server side is a must for the browser client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is refusing to send your request because the server you're sending the request to hasn't enabled CORS, at least not with those headers.

The only solution without modifying the server you're targeting is to write your own server that makes the request on behalf of the client.

Comment: So why did it work with the React-Native fetch @FakeRainBrigand?

Comment: React-Native apps run outside the same-origin web security model that prevents web apps from making cross-origin requests (unless the site the requests are sent to opts in by responding with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin ` header. React runs inside web-app code in a browser, and browsers are the only place where the cross-origin/CORS restrictions are  enforced. React-Native apps run outside the browser so they are not bound by any cross-origin restrictions (they don’t actually run from any origin, so the notion of “cross-origin” doesn’t apply to them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove whatever client-side code is setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` request header.

The header is a response header CORS-enabled servers send. You don’t set it from the client side.

Based on the error messages cited in the question, it sound like the server may already be correctly configured to send the right `Access-Control-*` headers. (Otherwise you’d instead be getting an error saying there’s no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response.)

The only error identifiable from the information in the question at this point is just that problem of the request including an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` request header that shouldn’t be there.

Comment: when I remove it - I get back to the "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: Yeah so I guess the API just not have no CORS support. At least if it’s https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/ then there is no indication there of CORS support, and no examples for using the API from web-app client-side code running in a browser.